# SwiftUI XCTest - How to increase velocity of scrolling?

Tags: swift, swiftui, scroll, xctest, xcuitest

I wrote a method that allows me to scroll list of elements on the screen for UI testing:

```
func scrollToElement(element: XCUIElement, maxScrolls: Int = 10) {
    var numberOfScrolls = 0
    while !element.isHittable, numberOfScrolls < maxScrolls {
        app.swipeUp()
        numberOfScrolls += 1
    }
}
```

Everything works fine but it takes too much time for the UI test to verify ie. wait until every scrolled view will be checked whether the element is available.
Is there any possible method or way to increase the velocity of scrolling?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about decreasing the item count and not touching the `ScrollView`?
Generally, it is not a good idea to manipulate UI components during tests. If you are using mock data, it might be better to lower the item count and still make it scrollable, but with fewer items this time.

Comment: Thank you @DoğuEmreDemirçivi for your answer. Unfortunately, in my case, it's not possible to describe the number of items on the list. That's the way I wanted to know whether it's possible to increase the velocity of scrolling. At least 10 maxScrolls will be fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

There's another version of performing swipe which you can use to set the speed

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/3551697-swipeup

```
func swipeUp(velocity: XCUIGestureVelocity)
```

for `XCUIGestureVelocity` please check:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuigesturevelocity